# Creating a form to search the database for a specific title

Tags: php, html, sql, database, forms

I'm trying to create a form so I can search a database for a specific title, but whenever I search nothing happens, I'm not sure how to connect to the database. Here's the link to the app:https://web-seanakiyama.c9users.io/Week%2011/Index3.php. Could someone help me figure this out, thankyou!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

require_once “week11.php”;

$search = "TITLE";
getGames($search);


<?php
$data = [
        ["TITLE" => "Counterstrike: Global Offensive", "DEVELOPER" => "Valve", "PUBLISHER" => "Valve", "PRICE" => 19.99, "PLATFORM" => "PC"],
        ["TITLE" => "Final Fantasy XV", "DEVELOPER" => "Square Enix", "PUBLISHER" => "Square Enix", "PRICE" => 99.99, "PLATFORM" => "PS4"],
        ["TITLE" => "Halo", "DEVELOPER" => "Bungie", "PUBLISHER" => "Microsoft", "PRICE" => 49.99, "PLATFORM" => "Xbox"],
        ["TITLE" => "Battlefield 4", "DEVELOPER" => "EA Digital Illusions", "PUBLISHER" => "EA", "PRICE" => 79.99, "PLATFORM" => "PC"]
]
?>

<html>
<head>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="jumbotron">                
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Games</h1>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="Search"</div>
                    <form>
                        <form class="form-inline">
                    <form action="index.php" method="get">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Title</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"/>
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="data"</div>
                <table>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Game Title</th>
                            <th>Developer</th>
                            <th>Publisher</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                            <th>Platform</th>
                        </thead>
                <?php
                 foreach($data as $data)
                {
                    echo"<tr>";
                    echo"<td>".$data["TITLE"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$data["DEVELOPER"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$data["PUBLISHER"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$data["PRICE"]."</td>";
                    echo"<td>".$data["PLATFORM"]."</td>";
                    echo"</tr>";
                }
                ?>
                </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just writting a simple code which have a form with one input named title and on submit this form will look into the table and show the matched search if found something matched in database, hope it would give you a little idea about search in table or database.

So firstly I am creating a form in searchform.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<--include your bootstrap here-->

</head>

<body>

<form name='search' class='form-horizontal' method='post'  action='search.php'>

    <div class='form-group'>

        <div class='col-sm-2'>
            <label for='title' class = 'control-label'>enter title to search</label>
        </div>

        <div class='col-sm-8'>
            <input type='text' name='title' id='title'>
        </div>

    </div>

    <input type='submit' name='search'  class='btn btn-info' value='search'>`

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

after this we will create a database named 'testsearch' in phpmyadmin and then create a table named search which would have two columns as 'id' and 'title' where I'd would be integer and title would be a varchar.

now we will create a new file named search.php  which would run when the form will be submitted and we will add the code written below in it.

```
<?php

//get the posted values
$submit = $_POST['search'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

//if submitted then rurun the code

if ($submit) {
    //create a database connection
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ' ');
    mysql_select_db('testsearch');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE 'title' = $title ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo 'search result is';

        foreach (mysql_fetch_array($result) as $row) {
            echo $row['title']; //print result
        }
    } else {
        echo 'no match found';
    }
}
```

Note : don't forget to insert values in the database too. to check it please insert some value into the table search and then run the form file in the browser and enter the title same as you have inserted in the table and it will show you appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

```
   require_once “week11.php”;

    $search = "TITLE";
    getGames($search); 
<?php
```

PHP tag should be at the top as you are including file using php tag

```
<?php
require_once “week11.php”;

$search = "TITLE";
getGames($search);
```